# open for write: permission denied but write_enable = YES

Tags: 14.04, server, ftp

I need to upload files via ftp to my website. I have changed permissions, added users, uncommented the `write_enable`, but nothing seems to work. I **ALWAYS** get `open for write: permission denied`

Any ideas on how to fix it?